# Add Font Awesome to Kentico 8.2 CkEditor

Tags: ckeditor, font-awesome, kentico

I'm trying to add font-awesome to kentico 8.2 ckeditor (v4.4.0).

After adding the relevant versions of fontawesome and it's dependancies, the widget plugin throws the following error: Uncaught TypeError: `CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler is not a function` at plugin.js line 3200:

```
//
// WIDGET STYLE HANDLER ---------------------------------------------------
//

( function() {

    /**
     * The class representing a widget style. It is an {@link CKEDITOR#STYLE_OBJECT object} like
     * the styles handler for widgets.
     *
     * **Note:** This custom style handler does not support all methods of the {@link CKEDITOR.style} class.
     * Not supported methods: {@link #applyToRange}, {@link #removeFromRange}, {@link #applyToObject}.
     *
     * @since 4.4
     * @class CKEDITOR.style.customHandlers.widget
     * @extends CKEDITOR.style
     */
    CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler( {
        type: 'widget',
```

CkEditor do not support bug reporting for older versions so I'm wondering if anyone else here has come across this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that function (addCustomHandler) in version 4.4.0 of ckeditor? If you do a search through all javascript, can you find it?

Otherwise, what i've done in the past is i created a Font-Awesome inline widget using my Transformable Web Part, i have it for 8.2, want me to export it for ya?

Comment: @TrevorJFayas that would be very kind of you!